# Correct way to use git version in a GitHub action .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, continuous-integration, github-actions, gitversion, dependabot-script

I have an API in .NET Core

I'm new in Github actions and I am trying to set a github action that everytime we send a PR, it updates the API project version. I'm working with dependabot, so the idea is that everytime a package is updated, the .NET Core API version is updated too.

I tried to follow this documentation https://gitversion.net/docs/ along but I'm unable to make this work. Does someone have any idea? Much appreciated.

This is what I have so far but I get an error.

```
---
name: CI/CD with Dependabot
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        dotnet-version:
          - 6.0.x
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
        with:
          dotnet-version: 6.0.x
      - name: Restore
        run: dotnet restore "Mango.Web"
      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build "Mango.Web" --configuration Release --no-restore
      - name: Publish
        run: dotnet publish "Mango.Web" --configuration Release --no-build
      - name: Install GitVersion
        uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/setup@v0
        with:
          versionSpec: 5.x
      - name: Determine Version
        id:   gitversion # id to later be referenced
        uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/execute@v0
      - name: Publish release with GitReleaseManager
        uses: gittools/actions/gitreleasemanager/publishv0
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          owner: someOwner
          tagName: 0.1.0
  dependabot:
    name: Dependabot fetch metadata
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.actor == 'dependabot[bot]' }}
    steps:
      - name: Dependabot metadata
        id: metadata
        uses: dependabot/fetch-metadata@v1
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          skip-commit-verification: false
```

This is the error, I know it might be because gitversion not being set correctly, but that's what I saw in the documentation.

`the` uses' attribute must be a path, a Docker image, or owner/repo@ref`

I tried to follow this documentation https://gitversion.net/docs/ along but I'm unable to make this work. Does someone have any idea? Much appreciated.

Comment: Since it is a .NET Core project, ignore all unrelated articles (I found them overcomplicated the basics), and just add the MSBuild task to your project to modify the version numbers, https://gitversion.net/docs/usage/msbuild

Comment: Typo, missing `@` before ref. Try: `uses: gittools/actions/gitreleasemanager/publish@v0` Looks like the typo is coming from their docs i.e. https://github.com/GitTools/actions/blob/main/docs/examples/github/gitreleasemanager/index.md. You might to [open an issue](https://github.com/GitTools/actions/issues/new/choose) for its fix. Apart from that, see [`jobs.<job_id>.uses`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_iduses) for more details on `uses` syntax.

Comment: I have raised a PR to fix up the docs here: https://github.com/GitTools/actions/pull/973